# JMeter Beanshell adds backslash to cookies values

Tags: json, cookies, jmeter, backslash, beanshell

The application for which I am preparing performance script is implemented on Sails and uses cookies for validating authentication for API calls. Using the HTTP Cookie Manager from JMeter did not help as it did not record all the cookie values. I was able to add them manually using beanshell preprocessor

The snippet of beanshell code:

```
CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
Cookie cookie1 = new Cookie("cookie1","someValue","localhost","/",false,0);
manager.add(cookie1);
```

This code successfully added cookie1 into cookies in JMeter.

I also need to add another cookie which has value similar to JSON.

```
CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
Cookie jsonCookie = new Cookie("cookie1","{\"Element\":{\"child1\":\"child1value\",\"child2\":\"child2value\"}","localhost","/",false,0);
manager.add(jsonCookie);
```

The value of this new cookie (jsonCookie) looks fine in the Debug Sampler. When I look for this same cookie in the Request, the Cookie variable has additional escape characters added to the doublequote.

```
Http Request Cookie Data:
cookie1=somevalue;jsonCookie="{\"Element\":{\"child1\":\"child1value\",\"child2\":\"child2value\"}"
Debug Sampler value
COOKIE_cookie1=somevalue
COOKIE_jsonCookie="{\"Element\":{\"child1\":\"child1value\",\"child2\":\"child2value\"}"
```

The addition of extra escape characters in the cookie data caused the authentication to fail. How do I make sure that the cookie values do not have these additional escape characters?

I have tried fetching these json values from User defined variables as well as passing them directly in Beanshell preprocessor. In both approach the resulting cookie value is the same.

Comment: `"` is not considered to be a safe character by some cookie standards and is escaped. You can try to use different "cookie policy" in CookieManager and see if that helps. On top of that, particular implementations of HTTP Request may also be inconsistent, and you will have to play with them. Total of 9x2 options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change "Cookie Policy" dropdown to `netscape` in order to remove these "extra slashes"

[image: JMeter Cookie Manager Policy Netscape]

And actually I don't see any need for scripting here as you can add a custom cookie via `User-Defined Cookies` section like:

[image: JMeter Define Cookie]

A couple more recommendations:

1. Don't run JMeter and application under test on the same machine as JMeter can be **very** resource intensive and you might get into situation when JMeter and application under test will be struggling for the OS resources
2. If you have to do scripting consider switching to [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language as when it comes to high loads [Beanshell performance might be a big question mark](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. It works like a charm, just the thing I was looking for :)